# Recover notebook Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there any way recover an .nb file? I tried to export to .pdf and all the content was lost.

Here's the error:
$ Failed.
6 line of corrupt data deleted.

I executed these two instructions in a new notebook:

Needs["AuthorTools`"]
NotebookRestore[]

but I got the error above.

Comment: Sorry, but what it your programming question? Can you provide a [mcve]? Some kind of instructions how to reproduce your problem? As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: 1. Might you possibly have a [backup](https://support.wolfram.com/34680)? 2. Can you open the .nb file in a text editor (be careful not to change it!)?